# Me arroja este error "El identificador formado por varias partes 'INSERTED.producto_id' no se pudo enlazar"

Tags: c#, sql-server

```
CREATE TRIGGER AñadirStockCompra ON detalle_compras

AFTER INSERT

AS

SELECT * FROM INSERTED

UPDATE p SET p.stock = p.stock + INSERTED.cantidad

FROM productos p

WHERE p.id = INSERTED.producto_id
```

Answer (score 0):

El SELECT del INSERTED lo tienes que unir al UPDATE.

```
CREATE TRIGGER AñadirStockCompra ON detalle_compras
AFTER INSERT
AS

UPDATE p SET 
     p.stock = p.stock + i.cantidad
FROM productos p
JOIN INSERTED i ON p.id = i.producto_id
```